# How to delete " before OAuth from authorization

Tags: java

i have question  when i send request use postman to another service and check on my fiddler i see my request like this for authorization :

```
Authorization: OAuth realm="xxxxxxx",oauth_consumer_key="xxxxxxxxaqwed",oauth_token="xxxxader",oauth_signature_method="HMAC-SHA256",oauth_timestamp="1639367815",oauth_nonce="LK6CQGSn8wb",oauth_version="1.0",oauth_signature="aeerdad"
```

but when i hit use java use this code

```
    headers.set(HttpHeaders.AUTHORIZATION, getAuthHeader(baseUrl));
```

i see my request like this

```
Authorization:"OAuth realm="xxxxxxx",oauth_consumer_key="xxxxxxxxaqwed",oauth_token="xxxxader",oauth_signature_method="HMAC-SHA256",oauth_timestamp="1639367815",oauth_nonce="LK6CQGSn8wb",oauth_version="1.0",oauth_signature="aeerdad"
```

my question is how to delete " before OAuth in my java code ? because i have try use to see what is value from getAuthHeader(baseUrl)
the value it is

when i System.out.println(getAuthHeader(baseUrl));
i got this

```
OAuth realm="xxxxxxx",oauth_consumer_key="xxxxxxxxaqwed",oauth_token="xxxxader",oauth_signature_method="HMAC-SHA256",oauth_timestamp="1639367815",oauth_nonce="LK6CQGSn8wb",oauth_version="1.0",oauth_signature="aeerdad"
```

there is no " before OAuth. but when i set on header there is adding " before OAuth. how to delete it ?

Comment: If you log `getAuthHeader(baseUrl)` what do you get?

Comment: OAuth realm="xxxxxxx",oauth_consumer_key="xxxxxxxxaqwed",oauth_token="xxxxader",oauth_signature_method="HMAC-SHA256",oauth_timestamp="1639367815",oauth_nonce="LK6CQGSn8wb",oauth_version="1.0",oauth_signature="aeerdad" here what i got @tgdavies

Comment: There's no extra quote character there, so why are you doing the `replace`?

Comment: because when i see my request on authorization there is adding " Before OAuth. so there is any adding "OAuth after Authorization: i think before i can handle adding "OAuth like that. but when i see the request i cannot handling that. still on that